# What is dharma as per Karna?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, karna

What is the definition of dharma as per Karna? I read somewhere that actions that weakens the soul is not dharma. Can anyone cite some reference on the same.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know who is Lord Karna? Can you please add more details?

Comment: @Triyugi i think he meant Suryaputr Karna.

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes ☺

Comment: probably supporting Adharm and Adharmi is Dharma as per Karna.

Comment: @Prasant You need to confirm urself if u really meant Karna or Lord Krishna.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande Forsaking friends or people who has helped one in times of distress is adharma.Thats y Karna stuck to Duryodhona although he knew that the later's path is not the right one.

Comment: **actions that weakens the soul is not dharma**--was he karna who said this?otherwise why is that quote related to this question?

Comment: @Rickross Thats what I said in my comment. He considered it his Dharm to support his friend(who helped him in times of distress) who was adharmi and hence chose to fight on side of Adharm. :)
BTW i dont think supporting some1 to ruin lives of so many people just because he helped you @ some point in life is a v good thing.

Comment: @Rickross please watch the video

Comment: @PrashantBhanarkar What video are you referring to? Can you edit & add link to your question?

Answer (score 4):

#### What is the definition of dharma as per Karṇa?

From [this conversation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05141.htm) between Kṛṣṇa and Karṇa from Udyoga-parva of Mahābhārata:

1. One should not let go of one's adopted parents if the real parents suddenly pop up one day.

   > Kunti, however, abandoned me without thinking of my welfare. The Suta, Adhiratha, as soon as he beheld me, took me to his home, and from her affection for me, Radha's breasts were filled with milk that very day, and she, O Madhava, cleansed my urine and evacuations. **How can one like us, conversant with duties and ever engaged in listening to scriptures deprive her [Radha] of her Pinda?**
   >
   > So also Adhiratha of the Suta class regardeth me as a son, and I too, from affection, always regard him as (my) father. O Madhava, that Adhiratha, O Janardana, from paternal affection caused all the rites of infancy to be performed on my person, according to the rules prescribed in the scriptures. It is that Adhiratha, again, who caused the name Vasusena to be bestowed upon me by the Brahmanas. When also I attained to youth, I married wives according to his selections. Through them have been born my sons and grandsons, O Janardana. My heart also, O Krishna, and all the bonds of affection and love, are fixed on them. From joy or fear. O Govinda. **I cannot venture to destroy those bonds even for the sake of the whole earth or heaps of gold.**
2. Never betray your friend to win your blood relatives.

   > In consequence also of my connection with Duryodhana of Dhritarashtra's race, I have, O Krishna, enjoyed sovereignty for thirteen years, without a thorn on my side. I have performed many sacrifices, always however in connection with persons of the Suta tribe. All my family rites and marriage rites have been performed with the Sutas. Obtaining me, O Krishna, Duryodhana hath, O thou of Vrishni's race, made this preparations for an armed encounter and provoked hostilities with the sons of Pandu. And it is for this, O Achyuta, that in the battle (that will ensue), I, O Krishna, have been chosen as the great antagonist of Arjuna to advance against him in a single combat. **For the sake of death, or the ties of blood, or fear, or temptation, I cannot venture, O Janardana, to behave falsely towards the intelligent son of Dhritarashtra.**

> I read somewhere that actions that weakens the soul is not dharma

Not sure where Karṇa says that, but if I find a reference I'll update my answer.